# Query with alais giving error Msg 7202

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a 20012 sql server with an alais eia-dev-db a user is trying to execute a query using the alais and they get an error:  Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 1 Could not find server 'eia-test-db' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

```
Select * from
[eia-dev-db].OutreachBusinessIntelligence.[dbo].[BI_D_tblProgramInformation]
```